# where can i download a canon mp640 pixma driver for linux

Tags: printing, canon

I have a canon mp640 and have lost the driver disc I need a way to download the driver for it. I have found the driver for window and mac but nothing for linux or ubuntu. I have Googled everything I could think of. Looked on the Canon website they only provide drivers for windows and mac.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google Search gave me this [link](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100236602.html).